# How to publish .NET WorkerService to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, worker-service

I have created a .NET WorkerService using the WorkerService template in Visual Studio.
It is a cross-platform and I have enabled the Linux startup configuration.

The problem is that AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio lacks the otption to publish a WorkerService project. The Web Application projects work as expected, but the WorkerService publish does not display the option in the AWS Toolkit UI.

Is there a way to publish the WorkerService project to  AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: You're absolutely correct, I have just passed this on to the .NET team at AWS for the feature to deploy worker services from Visual Studio to be considered.

Comment: In the meantime, you should be able to package it manually and deploy it to Elastic Beanstalk. Are you facing any issues or are you looking to see if an automated workflow exists?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I am very new to this, how do I package it manually? Is there a guide that I can follow? Thanks!

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I think that the issue is with the health checks. AWS uses HTTP request to verify health. With worker service, HTTP is not engaged, and so the health check will not work as expected.

Comment: Yes, there should be an option to deploy the service to a standalone EC2 instance. Elastic Beanstalk (EB) will be overkill - do you require EB? Why don't you just deploy your service to a 24/7 EC2 instance?